# Grails GORM cascade delete mapping

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

How to achieve `on delete cascade` in database level with GORM mapping with foreign keys?

I don't mean cascade delete in application level (sequentialy delete done by GORM).

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 5):

try adding static mapping with cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' in your domain class

e.g.

```
class Parent {
hasOne = [child: Child]

...

 static mapping = {
  child cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
 }


}

class Child {
 belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}
```

if you got time see this: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/GORM.html#cascades

hope this helps

Comment: It is on ORM level, not database level, as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 3):

GORM is an object relational mapper and it's implementation and responsibilities are within the application layer of your application. Your request, to have cascade deletes handled by your RDBMS (Postgres or MySQL) falls outside of the responsibilities of GORM.

However, it's entirely possible to implement cascading behavior at the RDBMS using triggers. See the respective documentation for how that is done. In addition, you will need to disable hibernate's second level cache (since your database will become out of sync with hibernate due to these changes).

Finally, to assist you with maintaining your triggers you can use the database migrations plugin/feature of Grails.

Good luck, but be careful since you are circumventing GORM/Hibernate/Grails.

Comment: Issue with grails db migration tool requesting support for db level cascades in migrations: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/67

Comment: Why? The `cascade` feature if a feature of GORM and doesn't implement it at the DB level. It's through GORM and doesn't effect the schema (since not all databases support such).

Comment: The DB migration tool reads the GORM and translates it into sql for updating the underlying database representation. The only thing in my gorm model that is not translated into a sql migration is the cascade functionality. As I use the postgres dialect, it would be useful to have the db migration tool support postgres cascades. I can add it by hand to my db migration constraint, but I'd like the option for the tool to handle it.

Comment: Then you should file it as a feature request, not a bug report. The `cascade` behavior in GORM was never intended to be implemented at a DB level.

Comment: Fair point. I originally thought it was a bug in db migration. I'll update the issue as a feature request.